# Video.js: Chapter selection (from .vtt file) not working / menu not showing (captions only working in FF)

Tags: html, video, video.js

Chapter selection is not working for me with the HTML5 video framework Video.js.
I searched a lot, but I cannot seem to to find any real solutions or working examples.

I like to use the chapters track with a .vtt file, but no menu is shown. No matter what I try.
I only try to get the example video working with it:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup="{}">
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
<track kind="chapters" src="chapters.vtt" srclang="en" label="Chapters" />
</video>
```

edit: I tried various options with and without the addition of 'default':

```
<track kind="chapters" src="chapters.vtt" srclang="en" label="Chapters" />
<track kind="chapters" src="chapters.vtt" srclang="en" label="Chapters" default />
<track kind="chapters" src="chapters.vtt" srclang="en" label="Chapters" default="default" />
```

The vtt file:

```
WEBVTT


chapter-1
 00:00.000 --> 00:03.500
 Intro

chapter-2
 00:03.501 --> 00:05.500
 This is Chapter 02

chapter-3
 00:05.501 --> 00:07.500
 This is Chapter 03
```

I don't even know how/where the menu should show up, because I'm unable to find any example.

By the way. 
The captions in the demo don't even work on all browsers (demo.captions.vtt). The player shows the 'CC' menu button, but the actual captions are not showing in IE10 or Chrome(27).

Answer (score 0):

For chapters, default is required if you want the chapters menu to show.
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/tracks.md#default

Adding default="default" to the track, should do the trick.

Comment: Firebug js console yields this error "d is undefined" when using the correct markup from the manual. This may be a bug in the player.

Answer (score 0):

I to am waiting for an answer to the very same question, 
however, I can answer your second problem. captions only work on IE, chrome, Safari when hosting they will not work using local files, so if u test it out with xamp(mac) or wamp(windows) the captions should show. If you find out how to make chapters work let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There does appear to be a bug in the player. I have tested it and it seems to be in line 1455 of video.dev.js (version 4.1.0).

Hopefully we'll hear from them soon about this apparent bug.